# How to estimate a two-level, driven, AR(1) process

Tags: autoregressive

I would like to estimate the following model:
$$
y_t = (1-a)\,y_{t-1} + a\,\mathbf{b}^T\mathbf{x}_t + \epsilon_t \\
z_t = (1-c)\,z_{t-1} + c\,y_{t}
$$
where $z_t$ and $\mathbf{x}_t$ are observed, $\epsilon_t$ is white noise, and we seek to estimate $a$, $\mathbf{b}$, and $c$; note that $a$ and $c$ are scalars and $\mathbf{b}$ is a vector.
Thus $y_t$ is a driven (is that the right term?) AR(1) process, however it is not observed.  Instead a smoothed version, $z_t$, is what is observed.

How can such a model be estimated?

Comment: Perhaps(!), cast the model into state-space form? With $y_{t}$ as an unobserved state variable, you'll be able to obtain estimates via a Kalman filter. Estimates can be obtained using maximum likelihood - and prediction error decomposition.

Comment: Thanks @GraemeWalsh, I'll need to give your suggestion some thought.